# Clash of Clans crashes when I click the Donate Troops button

Tags: technical-issues, clash-of-clans

I'm leader of clan and I can't donate troops in the Clan War Castle. When I click the donate button, the game crashes and my mobile home page is displayed.

What causes this? Is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug that was introduced in the th11 update. See the full list [here](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/934438-Town-Hall-11-update-Bugs-Problems-thread). It is generally caused by having a barracks or dark barracks or dark spell factory upgrading. There is no fix for this yet, though once your upgrade completes, it seems to work again.